# Different calculation result using Python

Tags: python

I've got a weird case using Python to get the result of this calculation:

```
11.66 * 0.98 * 1.05 + 1.7 + 0.70 * 1.03
```

in Python the result that I got is **14.41914**

but when my customer calculate it using their calculator and iPhone the result that they got is **14.8300842**

so which is the correct result ?
and what caused this calculation to have different result ?
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct result is the one Python gave you. Your customer is using a calculator that doesn't account for order of operations, or has used the calculator in such a way that order of operations information was discarded.

Comment: stupid of me to figure it out now, thanks ur for guidance dude :)

Answer (score 7):

What your customer seems to have done is this:

```
>>> (11.66*0.98*1.05 + (1.7+0.7))*1.03
14.830084200000002
>>>
```

whereas that expression in python:

```
>>> 11.66*0.98*1.05 + 1.7+0.7*1.03
14.419140000000001
```

Does the multiplies first:

```
>>> (11.66*0.98*1.05) + 1.7+(0.7*1.03)
14.419140000000001
```

Its a very strong convention that multiplication is done first, but desk calculators (real and appy) have to work on the numbers as they are punched in, so might do different things.

Comment: reverse calculating ftw!

Answer (score 2):

14.41914 is right.

(((((11.66 * 0.98) * 1.05) + 1.7) + 0.70) * 1.03) = 14.8300842

So they just ignore the calculation order of adding and multiplication.

Comment: If only RPN calculators had caught on, we wouldn't be in this mess!